# Altering a new table php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created a new table that extracts data from a website and creates new columns from the website and that works fine. I would add a extra column in that I want but it is going through an array that will add the new column a numerous amount of times. The code that I have added to add one more column doesn't do anything.

Here is the part of the code that doesn't work

```
mysql_query('ALTER TABLE '. $tablename. 'ADD Home VARCHAR(30)');
```

Here is the code with the array put into columns

```
$tablename = 'team';
$columns = array();

foreach ($player_fromsite as $player_name) {
   $columns[] = '`' . str_replace($space, $replacespace, $player_name) . '` VARCHAR(30)';
}

$query = 'CREATE TABLE `' . $tablename . '` (' . implode(',', $columns) . ')';
mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query('ALTER TABLE '. $tablename. 'ADD Home VARCHAR(30)');

echo "Table Created!";
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the column in the first place?

Comment: I creating alot of new tables

Comment: Regardless, as Jessica said, you can add 'Home' as a column during the initial creation by adding it to the `$columns` array before you implode it: `array_push($columns, 'Home')` (or I guess `$columns[] = 'Home'`, if that's more idiomatic for PHP);

Comment: Yeah how is that relevant?

Comment: I can try that but would prefer coding it in

Comment: I should be able to code it in. It is just good practice

Answer (score 2):

You need a space between your table name and "add...":

```
mysql_query('ALTER TABLE '. $tablename. ' ADD Home VARCHAR(30)');
```